# python (numpy array) indicess 1d array like a 2d array with array[x,y]

Tags: arrays, numpy, indices

I am pretty new to python and I try to read data from an array with unknown size (but in general 2D). Not that hard but my problem occurs when I try to get a value with e.g.:
array[0,0]
but the size of the array is 1x1000, because then it is is only a 1D array and only array[0] is accepted.

Is there a shorty way around it or do I have to check for the dimensions first and make a case discrimination?

Yours sincerely,
Thomas

Comment: My "Hello everyone" was deleted unintentionally, sorry for that..

Comment: In `numpy` the number of dimensions can be 0, 1, 2 or more.  So you need to be aware of the `shape` and `ndim`.  When you say the size is 1x1000` do you mean the shape is (1,1000) or (1000,)?  In numpy that difference is significant.  In general you need to track the number of dimensions of an array, and index it accordingly.

Comment: ok than I have a array with (1000,), and is I read out of your post i would need a (1,1000), correct? does this work with reshape?

Comment: got it, array.resize([1,1000]) makes my (1000,)-array to an (1,1000)-array. Thanks for the helpful comment, food for thought ;-)